# $\delta (G)+\Delta (G)\geq p-1$ then $G$ is a related graph and $diam(G)≤4$

Tags: graph-theory

Show that, if  $\delta (G)+\Delta (G)\geq p-1$ then $G$ is a related graph and $diam(G)≤4$
I´ve already proved that is related by contradiction, but I have troubles with the second part, I´ve just prove the result for regular graphs, please help!
Thanks for any comment!

Comment: What is a "related graph," and what does $p$ denote with respect  to $G$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $v$ be a a vertex of maximum degree and let $S$ consists of $v$ and its neighbors. Then
$|S| \ge p - \delta(G)$. Let $T = V(G) \setminus S$, then we have $|T| \le \delta(G)$.

Notice that every vertex in $T$ must have a neighbor in $S$. Now, we have :

The distance between any two vertices in $S$ is at most two.

The distance between a vertex in $S$ and a vertex in $T$ is a most 3 and

The distance between any two vertices in $T$ is at most four.

Answer (score 0):

Let $u, v$ be 2 non adjacent vertices of $G$. It suffices to show that there is a $(u,v)-$walk of length at most $4$ in $G$.

If $\deg{u} + \deg{v} \ge n-1$, then from the pigeonhole principle there is a vertex in $G$ that is adjacent to both $u$ and $v$ and so G contains a $(u,v)-$path of length 2. So we may assume that $\deg{u} + \deg{v} < n-1$.

Hence, $\deg{u} \le \Delta (G)$ and $\deg{v} \le \Delta (G)$. Let $w \in V(G)$ with $\deg{w} = \Delta (G)$. Then
$$
 \deg{u} + \deg{w} =  \deg{u} + \Delta(G) \ge \delta(G) + \Delta(G)\ge n-1 
$$
and so(pigeonhole principle) there exists $x \in V(G)$ such that $x$ is adjacent to $u$ and $w$. Similarly,  $\deg{v} + \deg{w} \ge n-1 $ and so there exists $y \in V(G)$ such that $y$ is adjacent to $v$. Therefore $(u,x,w,y,v)$ is a $(u,v)-$walk of length $4$ in $G$.